# Meteor - How to load a JS library for only specific users?

Tags: meteor

I'm designing an administration interface with graphics and so on and I'm using the Highcharts Library (140kb). I want this file to be loaded only for admin users. What would be the best way to do it?

[I just saw that we could use Iron-Router to conditionally load JavaScript](http://empire5.com/development/meteor-using-iron-router-to-conditionally-load-javascript-libraries/)  but I don't like the idea to handle this kind of things inside the router as below:

```
Router.map ->
  @route 'admin',
    path: '/admin'
    template: 'admin'
    action: ->
      $.getScript '/js/moment.min.js', (data, textStatus, jqxhr) ->
        if jqxhr.status is 200
          @render()
```

**NOTE**: I wrote a little blog post [to load a library for only specific users with Meteor.](http://journal.gentlenode.com/meteor-15-load-a-library-only-for-specific-users/)

Comment: why would the same trick not work in a regular meteor js file?

Comment: @ChristianFritz because the code would all still get sent down from the wire even if it wasn't used. The OP is asking for an approach that actually doesn't send the data over.

Comment: Yes I think that the only solution that comes to my mind is to put the file in the public directory so as to avoid sending the data over the wire and call it with $.getScript() as @ChristianFritz explained below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this not work (on the client)?

```js
var loaded = false;
Deps.autorun(function() {
    if (!loaded && isAdmin(Meteor.userId())) {
        $.getScript("/js/moment.min.js");
        loaded = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes it works on the client. I will do something like that. Thank you.